# iOS voice over called on UIButton regardless of accessibility disabled

Tags: ios, voiceover

I have disabled the Accessibility option of a UIButton in the identity inspector but voice over still reads out the text when the item is clicked. What's the problem?

I'm developing for iOS >= 6.1 on Xcode 5

Comment: "When the item is clicked" how are you able to tap the button if it's not an accessibility element?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist accessibility is not a requirement for buttons to be "tappable"

Answer (score 10):

try

```
button.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
```

this should works

Comment: This works because even though the `UIButton` is not an accessibility element the `UILabel` inside of it is still seen as UIKit traverses through the accessibility tree. Enabling this hides all of its children, including the label.

Comment: @Keith Smiley : why is `UIButton` not an accessible element ? It inherits UIView whose children should be accessible, shouldn't they ?